# Problems with building a multiCanvas

Tags: objective-c, c4

I'm trying to make a multiCanvas and everything seems right since xcode has not given me any errors. However, my build crashes, and I can't seem to find what the problem is. Can someone please review my code and see if there is something missing? If there is a problem how could I fix it?

I've basically been following the tutorial on the c4 website.

BUT here is my code:

```
    //
    //  C4WorkSpace.m
    //  Mudascode
    //
    //  Created by Mudassir Iqbal on 2013-10-06.
    //`enter code here`

    #import "C4Workspace.h"
    #import "WorkSpaceBViewController.h"

    @implementation C4WorkSpace
    {
        // placing the images created into the canvas
        // i_button = insulin button, display = ipad icon, reset = reset button
        C4Image * i_button;
        C4Image * display;
        C4Image * reset;

    //variables used to define the location of buttons
    // img_placement = location of the images, text_placement = location of the text
    CGPoint img_placement;
    CGPoint text_placement;

    //labels to make madditional information visible and make app ui frindly 
    C4Label * status;
    C`enter code here`4Label * condition; // status = number output, condition = high, good, low
    C4Font  * font_use; // font_use = font type
    C4Timer * timer;// timer = timer to tell you that you forgot to take insulin

    //lets start with adding an int to represent the sugar level
    // CHANGE THIS RANGE.. I dunno what's the highest possible insulin range is
    //figured it out!!!
    int insulinNumber;

    // this is the text that you input...will be parsed to int
    NSString * insulinValue;
   }
//creating a variable for the new subclass
WorkSpaceBViewController * workSpaceB;
C4View * currentView;

-(void)setup
{

    [self inputInsulinValue];
    [self imageCreate];// creates interface
    [self statusUpdate];// the condition in numbers
    [self conditionUpdate];// the condition of sugar


    //addding the tap gesture so that the button will work 
    [i_button addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped:"];
    [self listenFor:@"tapped:" fromObject:i_button andRunMethod:@"insulinNumber"];// tap on button

    [reset addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped:"];
    [self listenFor:@"tapped:" fromObject:reset andRunMethod:@"inputInsulinValue"];// tap on button

    [self createWorkSpaces];

}



//********************************************
// updates the number of the screen


-(void) statusUpdate
{


    font_use = [C4Font fontWithName:@"futura" size:35.0f]; // sets a font

    NSString * ins = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", insulinNumber];

    status = [C4Label labelWithText:ins font: font_use]; // sets a number on screen

    status.textAlignment = ALIGNTEXTCENTER;         // aligns label
    [status setCenter:CGPointMake(226, 428)];       // sets label in center
    [status sizeToFit];
    status.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.85f     // uses magenta text color
                                       green:0.22f
                                        blue:0.31f
                                       alpha:1.0f];

    [self.canvas addSubview:status];
    // add to screen
}

//******************************----************


// updates the phrase (high, good, low) on screen
-(void) conditionUpdate
{


    font_use = [C4Font fontWithName:@"futura" size:21.0f];

    condition = [C4Label labelWithText:@"Calculating..." font: font_use];
    condition.textAlignment = ALIGNTEXTCENTER;
    [condition setCenter:CGPointMake(250, 582)];
    [condition sizeToFit];
    condition.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.85f
                                          green:0.22f
                                           blue:0.31f
                                          alpha:1.0f];

    [self.canvas addSubview:condition];
}



// text input box

//*******************************************


-(void)inputInsulinValue
{

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Recorder" message:@"Please enter your glucose level:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    alertTextField.placeholder = @" enter glucose level";

    [alert show];

}
//********************************************


// runs automatically after pressing enter... updates the numbers in variables
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{
    insulinValue = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    insulinNumber = [insulinValue intValue];

    status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", insulinNumber];
    [status sizeToFit];
    [self condition];
}


//***********************************************


// sets up the images
-(void) imageCreate {

    i_button = [C4Image imageNamed:@"i_button.png"];
    display = [C4Image imageNamed:@"display.png"];
    reset = [C4Image imageNamed:@"reset.png"];

    [self.canvas addSubview: i_button];
    [self.canvas addSubview: display];
    [self.canvas addSubview: reset];

    img_placement.x = 320;
    img_placement.y = 512;

    display.center = img_placement;

    img_placement.x += 320;
    img_placement.y = 400;
    i_button.center = img_placement;

    img_placement.y += 300;
    reset.center = img_placement;

    display.userInteractionEnabled = NO;


}
//*****************************************************


// if insulin button is pressed, a random number displays and tells you if you're good, high, or low
-(void) insulinNumber
{
    //test to see if things are going smoothly 
    // C4Log (@"pokemon");

    insulinNumber  = [C4Math randomInt:400];
    status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", insulinNumber];
    [status sizeToFit];
    [self condition];
    timer = [C4Timer automaticTimerWithInterval:60.0f target:self method:@"update" repeats:YES];
}


//*****************************************************


// makign a conditions for the insulin levels so that message relates to the 
-(void) condition {

    if (insulinNumber <70)
        condition.text = @"Your blood sugar level is low.";
    else if (insulinNumber > 70 && insulinNumber <90)
        condition.text = @"Your blood sugar level is good.";
    else
        condition.text = @"Your blood sugar level is high.";
    [condition sizeToFit];
    //write the rang and change the text to whatever


}
//*****************************************************

-(void)createWorkSpaces {
       workSpaceB = [[WorkSpaceBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"workSpaceB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    CGFloat offSet = self.canvas.width * 0.05f;
    workSpaceB.canvas.frame = CGRectMake(offSet,
                                         offSet,
                                         self.canvas.width - 2 * offSet,
                                         self.canvas.height - 44 - 2 * offSet);

    [workSpaceB setup];


    [self.canvas addSubview:workSpaceB.canvas];
    currentView = (C4View *)self.canvas;



}
//*****************************************************

-(void)createToolBar {
    CGRect toolBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.canvas.height - 44, self.canvas.width, 44);
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolBarFrame];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;


    UIBarButtonItem * flexible;
    flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];



    UIBarButtonItem *b2;
    b2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"WorkSpace B"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
    target:self
    action:@selector(switchToB)];
    [toolBar setItems:@[flexible, b2, flexible]];


    [self.canvas addSubview:toolBar];

}

//*****************************************************
-(void)switchToView:(C4View *)view transitionOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
{
    if(![currentView isEqual:view]) {
        [UIView transitionFromView:currentView
                            toView:view
                          duration:0.75f
                           options:options
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            currentView = view;
                            finished = YES;
                        }];
    }
}

-(void)switchToB
{
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown;
    [self switchToView:(C4View*)workSpaceB.canvas transitionOptions:options];
}


//*****************************************************
@end
```

when i run this, it crahes and i get this error
        #import

```
#import "C4AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([C4AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: the because you're using additional classes we will need to see more than just the code in your `C4WorkSpace.m` can you zip your entire project and post it somewhere that we can download it? GitHub would be ideal for this!

Comment: Just pinging you to provide code.